# Extract repeated observations of single column in a list of dataframes R

Tags: r, dataframe, nested-lists

I have the following reproducible example:

```
# I have 4 dataframes in a listy with a few observations that repeat themselves
df_1 <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4), y = c('apple', 'pineapple', 'orange', 'grape'))
df_2 <- data.frame(x = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), y = c('watermelon', 'orange', 'halibut', 'apple', 'iron', 'grape'))
df_3 <- data.frame(x = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 0), y = c('rock', 'pineapple', 'apple', 'tire', 'bomb', 'star', 'coconut', 'grape'))
df_4 <- data.frame(x = c(1, 4, 9), y = c('grape', 'apple', 'rock'))

# All inside a another list
df_list <- list(df_1, df_2, df_3, df_4)
```

I want a function that returns the values that are repeated in the `y` column in each dataframe, disregarding the order of the observation in the column, so the result of the function should only be:

```
[1] "apple" "grape"
```

I have tried `reduce(intersect, big_list)` but the function is not capturing all the repeated values across the dataframes. It may be because the position of the repeated value in each column is not the same or because column sizes are not equal between dataframes in list.

Comment: My bad, you won't get the data.frame errors anymore, just edited the question. On your first comment, there are 2 strings that repeat themselves in the 4 data.frames, `apple` and `grape`. You can check it on the code.

Comment: So to be clear, you're not looking for values that are repeated _within_ each data frame? You are looking for values repeated _across_ all the data frames? Why does the output not also include `"rock"`, which appears in the third and fourth data frame? Orange and pineapple also appear more than once.

Comment: Yes, not within but across all data frames. I don't want neither `rock` nor `orange` because I'm trying to find common observations across multiple dataframes that will be helpful to draw relationships across the multiple data frames I am working with

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by multiple. `"rock"` appears in two different data frames. Are you saying you want values that appear in more than two data frames? But not if they appear multiple times in the same data frame.

Comment: Or are you saying you are looking for values that appear in _all_ data frames?

Comment: The answer I want is `apple` and `grapes` because they appear in all 4 data frames, I don't want `rock`, for example, because it appears only in 2 of the 4. Same goes with `orange` or `pineapple`. The function must return the values of the `y` column that appear in all 4 dataframes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find values that appear in all data frames, you can use `Reduce()` to apply `intersect()` to each `y` column (which we can extract with `lapply()`).

```r
Reduce(intersect, lapply(df_list, \(df) df$y))
# [1] "apple" "grape"
```

Alternatively, you can do:

```r
Reduce(
    \(df1, df2) intersect(df1, df2$y),
    df_list[-1],
    init = df_list[[1]]$y
)
# [1] "apple" "grape"
```

Comment: Thanks, why do you use `\(df)`? I don't know that sintax

Comment: @toku_mo it's just the same as `function(df)` - see e.g. [here](https://www.jumpingrivers.com/blog/new-features-r410-pipe-anonymous-functions/)

Answer (score 1):

You only need to adjust the input and `reduce` only `y` columns:

```
> reduce(map(df_list, \(x) pluck(x, "y")), intersect)       
[1] "apple" "grape"
```

Edit: same-same with @SamR's answer, but with `reduce`, `map` and `pluck` from `purrr`.

Answer (score 0):

Another long way to achieve this:

```
library(tidyverse)
list_rbind(df_list) |> group_by(y) |> summarize(n = n()) |> filter(n==4) |> select(y)
```